# How to prevent usercontrol fill option from extending too far

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dock

I have a usercontrol that I'm adding as a control of a main form dynamically. The Mainform is basically empty, except it has a large status bar on bottom.

Problem is, when I set the Dockstyle.Fill option on my usercontrol, the size of the loaded usercontrol extends beyond the statusbar (It fills the entire main form as if the status bar wasn't there).

How do I prevent this behavior? This is an example of how I dynamically load my form

```
        logicForm = new LogicForm();
        this.Controls.Add(logicForm);
        logicForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Comment: Could you please share the `.aspx` code of your page?

Comment: ?? This is winforms, not asp.net.

Comment: Im sorry. Never saw any reference to winforms; except maybe the reference to Docksyle.

Comment: <facepalm> Alright. I think I need to remove useless comments to save space. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution

I need to bring the form to front in order to properly dock it if I already have some other controls on the main form:

```
logicForm.BringToFront();
```

Found here: http://dotnetref.blogspot.kr/2008/08/using-dock-fill-on-control-when-you.html

-________________________-

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the DockStyle to None and use the Anchor property instead.

Set the anchor to Top,Bottom,Left,Right and size your control to fill all the space up to the status bar.

You should find when you run that the user control will then resize with the form.